# R Error with openNLPmodels.pt for Portuguese

Tags: r, opennlp

I'm running into error while trying to work with openNLPmodels.pt for POS tagging the Portuguese sentence. However the model for English i.e., openNLPmodels.en works fine with English sentences.

Appreciate any help.

## R Code

```
# R Code #
install.packages("openNLPmodels.pt", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at/", type="source") 

library(openNLP)
library(NLP)
library(openNLPmodels.pt)

s <- paste("Um esquilo preto raro se tornou um visitante regular de um jardim suburbano.")

# For reference here is the English version of sentence #
# s <- paste("A rare black squirrel has become a regular visitor to a suburban garden.")
###

## Sentence token annotations.
sent_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator(language = "pt", probs = FALSE, model ='openNLPmodels.pt')

# Code End #
```

## Error

```
# Error #
Error in .jnew("java.io.FileInputStream", model) : 
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: openNLPmodels.pt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a stupid solution, although working:

1) download the portuguese model from here (i took the pt-pos-maxent.bin):
http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/

2) and then replace the English model in the path:
depends-on-your-computer\R\win-library\3.4\openNLPdata\models\en-pos-maxent.bin

After these steps, then running the command:

`word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator(language = "en")`

as specified here:
[How to use OpenNLP to get POS tags in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995232/how-to-use-opennlp-to-get-pos-tags-in-r)

Then the classifiers performs bad for english and good for portuguese ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried modifying the code you sent and the problem seems to be "model ='openNLPmodels.pt'

If you set it to 'model = NULL', it might work, as in

```
sent_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator(language = "pt", probs = FALSE, model =NULL)
```

When you use the option "NULL" in model, the default options for the language you select are used, so it should be ok.

Note, though, that the second and the third arguments you used are the default options, so you could simply omit them.

The problem I'm having is with the Parse_Annotator command, but that's another issue I'm posting here soon.

Comment: thanks Rodrigo. By default it would use the openNLP model for a given language from http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/. However we can specify a model which we would like to use so I was trying the openNLPmodels.pt, currently this seems to be the only other model available. Parse_Annotator works fine for me, provided JAVA_HOME is set properly.

Comment: Rodrigo Araujo, what is the exact error message that you are facing with the Parse_Annotator? The R code from your other post worked fine for me and gives the expected tags. Sorry I could not comment in that post for additional info as I would need 50 reputation to do so.

Comment: Manohar S, I tested this code again and this last package (openNLPmodels.pt) doesn't work for version 3.1.2 - and neither the package openNLPmodels.en . When I posted this question I believe one of them was working, but now it doesn't. If your are interested, you could refer to the link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475380/problems-using-opennlpmodels-pt-for-portuguese) for further comments.